# Can QR-Code execute objective-c-data?

Tags: xcode, qr-code

Most of the QR-Code-Generators in internet give you the option to use the QR-Code as link for websites, some text or to a phone number. But is it possible to implement an app with QR-code scanner which scans a QR-Code and this QR-code acts then as a Button which links to another 'page' in the same app?

more precisely what I meant: For example: Someone scans the QR-code and this executes that a button appears which links to a specific site in my App (not a weblink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, taken in account that it is your app. You could for example implement a lua interpreter and run code from a special website, linked with a url, but i'm not completely sure if it is apple approved.

Comment: I think that's also somehow what I want. Is there any further information for this where I can about it?

Comment: Hah, embedding Lua, nice trick. It can get a lot done in the roughly-2KB available.

Comment: No, I don't think so. @sarnold Or you could make a webpage for hosting the code served by qr codes

Comment: Is there any further information in internet or at least which keywoards to use for finding further information?

Answer (score 2):

Your application is free to interpret the data in a QR code in any fashion you wish. If you wanted the text: "Add Button: HELLO" to add a new button labeled `HELLO`, you could sure do that -- though don't expect it to add new executable code.

Comment: that's exactly what I want! The QR-Code then adds a button and this button links to another page in my App (not to a weblink). Is there any documentation in internet to read how to do that?

Comment: Personnaly, I think it's better to have also a "normal URL" to handle the other Scanner APP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use simple text in the QRcode that are a "specific code" for your app to act the button.

Or if you want your QRcode can be read by other "Scanner", add some code at the end : like this:

```
http://normal.url.for/reader#your-specific-code
```

Comment: ah okay, I will try it out then if this simple text is enough.